# reshape long to wide aggregated by multiple variables while keeping the original repeated rows

Tags: r

I have this question that might be a reshaping or a merging problem.

```
id = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5))
type = factor(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
              labels = c('pay','inv'))
lett = c('a', 'b', 'a_inv','a_inv', 'b_inv', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', NA)
numb = c(30, 30, -10, -20, -30, -20, -20,  20, 20, NA)
abs_numb = abs(numb)

test = data.frame(id, type, lett, numb, abs_numb)
test

   id type  lett numb abs_numb
1   1  pay     a   30       30
2   1  pay     b   30       30
3   1  inv a_inv  -10       10
4   1  inv a_inv  -20       20
5   1  inv b_inv  -30       30
6   2  inv     c  -20       20
7   2  inv     c  -20       20
8   2  pay     d   20       20
9   2  pay     d   20       20
10  2  pay  <NA>   NA       NA
```

I would like to reshape this long table into a wide table, aggregated by `id`, `abs_numb` and separated by `type`. Something like this:

```
  id abs_numb numb_inv numb_pay  lett_pay  lett_inv
  1       30  -30         30        b         b_inv
  1       10  -10         NA        NA        a_inv
  1       20  -20         NA        NA        a_inv
  1       30   NA         30        a         NA
  2       20  -20         20        d         c
  2       20  -20         20        d         c
  2       NA   NA         NA        <NA>      <NA>
```

I have two repeated rows in the data set (`id == 2, abs_numb == 20`), if I aggregate on this it will just return one line. But I need to keep both in the wide dataset for counting purposes. If I first split the dataset based on `type == pay` and `type == inv` and then merge on `id` and `abs_numb`, it will return four lines, when I only need two.

My dataset is kind of big, so I wonder if there's an efficient way to achieve this. 
Thank you in advance!